# Edit respective element on list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I'm making 2 lists. List of boys and girls. The button creates new element for each. Soo I want when i click for example boy1 element. Edit girl1 element. And change the color to black. When i click boy 2 edit girl2 and so on.
This is my Html

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<input type="button" value="Add new" id="clickme"onclick="addElements()">
  <ul id="boys">
      <li id="boy1">Boy1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="girls">
      <li id="girl1">Girl 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
#boys {
  color:red;
}
#girls {
  color:blue;
}
li {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

And JavaScript

```
 var i = 1;
    $("#clickme").click(function() {
      i++
        $("#boys").append("<li id='boy" + i+"'>Boy"+ i +"</li>");
            $("#girls").append("<li id='girl" + i+"'>Girl"+ i +"</li>")
  });
```

The example of result should look like this

[image]

Comment: it sound easy but please explain this more =>  when i click for example boy1 element. Edit girl1 element. And change the color to black. When i click boy 2 edit girl2,, normally you click on thew element that u want to edit not click on an element and edit another one

Comment: Yeah but I want to edit respective element. For example $("#boy1).click(function(){$("#girl1).css("color","black")}), something like this. And i want to do this for all elements. Is it clear

Comment: ok clear ,, wait a sec plz

Comment: for some reason even ur function addElements is not working properly, ill have to work more around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate event on the parent div:

```js
$(function () {
  var i = 1;
  $("#clickme").click(function() {
    i++
    $("#boys").append("<li id='boy" + i+"'>Boy"+ i +"</li>");
    $("#girls").append("<li id='girl" + i+"'>Girl"+ i +"</li>")
  });
  
  // attach event handler for all li elements: also for
  // the one created dynamically
  $('div.mainDiv').on('click', 'li', function(e){
    if (this.id.indexOf('boy') != -1) {
      $('#girl' + this.id.substr(3)).css("color", "black");
    } else {
      $('#boy' + this.id.substr(4)).css("color", "black");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#boys {
  color:red;
}
#girls {
  color:blue;
}
li {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <input type="button" value="Add new" id="clickme">
    <ul id="boys">
        <li id="boy1">Boy1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="girls">
        <li id="girl1">Girl1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Look bro. I don't want to change the color of clicked element. I want to change the color of respective. So if I click boy1. Change the color of girl 1. Is that clear

Comment: @ShkelqimMaxharraj Sorry, snippet updated. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it may helpful for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#clickme").click(function() {
    i++
    $("#boys").append("<li id='boy" + i + "' onclick='fnEdit(id)'>Boy" + i + "</li>");
    $("#girls").append("<li id='girl" + i + "'>Girl" + i + "</li>")
  });
});

function fnEdit(id) {
  var sBoyId = id.toString();
  var genId = sBoyId.replace(/boy/g, '');
  $("#" + id).siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $("#" + id).addClass("selected");
  $("#girl" + genId).siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $("#girl" + genId).addClass("selected").attr("contenteditable", "true");

}
```

```css
#boys {
  color:red;
}
#girls {
  color:blue;
}
li {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.selected{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
<input type="button" value="Add new" id="clickme">
<ul id="boys">
  <li id="boy1" onclick="fnEdit(id)">Boy1</li>
</ul>

<ul id="girls">
  <li id="girl1">Girl 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hope you saw the answer @Shkelqim Maxharraj. Please let me know if you still need any extra functionalities for it.